# Why isn't type(string) equal to "<class 'str'>"?

Tags: python

In Python 3 `type('jjj')=="<class 'str'>"`, it evaluates to `False`, while in Python 2 `type('jjj')=="<type 'str'>"` has the same results. Don't know why is this happening, so any help (even a little push) is appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because the `type` function doesn't return a string. It returns a type 'type':

```
>>> type(type('hi'))
<type 'type'>
```

So what you're doing at the moment is comparing a type 'type' to a type 'string', which will have the result `False`.

I recommend using `isinstance`:

```
>>> isinstance('hi', str)
True
```

Answer (score 3):

Confusion can be induced  by shells. Some displays the type name when other print the representation of the type.

As an illustration

- python shell

  ```
  >>>type('jj')
  <class 'str'>
  ```
- Ipython

  ```
  In [68]: type('a')
  Out[68]: str
  ```

Here the two string used:

```
In [69]: str.__name__
Out[69]: 'str'

In [70]: repr(str)
Out[70]: "<class 'str'>"
```

As said  `isinstance` is the good way to test a type.

Comment: Nice explanation of different ways to get an object's type and their results! However, I'm confused by "shells". Also, would you try this in Python, not IPython please.